# Best spell checking api for Java

Tags: java, spell-checking

What is the best Java spell checking API?

Free or purchased, must be royalty-free.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for Java spell checker library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library)

Answer (score 7):

Just used [Jazzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/) and it worked well. Try this [example](http://jazzy.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/jazzy/jazzy/src/com/swabunga/spell/examples/SpellCheckExample.java?view=markup) and download the [dictionary](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/files/Dictionaries/English/).

Here's the [Maven dependency](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3a%22net.sf.jazzy%22%20AND%20a%3a%22jazzy%22):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jazzy</groupId>
    <artifactId>jazzy</artifactId>
    <version>0.5.2-rtext-1.4.1-2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Sentry Spell Checker](http://www.wintertreesoftware.com/spell-check/java/index.html) seems interesting. It supports dialog-based spell checking and as-you-type highlighting of misspelled words. It's a commercial product ($399 for the engine), but there are no royalty fees.

[Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) is a simpler, open source alternative. It's been around for awhile, but doesn't seem to be under active development anymore. On the bright side, it is free (LGPL license).

I would look at Jazzy first to see if it fits your needs. There's a demo applet [here](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/demo.html) where you can try it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple other I have heard of, but I don't know if they are any good.

Rapidspell and JTextCheck