# Looking for Java spell checker library

Tags: java, nlp, spell-checking, languagetool

I am looking for an open source Java spell checking library which has dictionaries for at least the following languages: French, German, Spanish, and Czech. Any suggestion?

Comment: If a local dictionary is not required a cloud endpoint that works is Sapling: (https://sapling.ai/docs/api/spellcheck). Additionally, French, German, and Spanish support grammar checking.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should check out [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) its used in some high profile Java applications. Two problems with it:

1. It has not been updated since 2005.
2. There is only English dictionary on their SourceForge page.

There are some third party dictionaries floating around. I had one for French, last time I used jazzy.

Comment: @Infamy Jazzy looks like the best candidate. For dictionaries, the OpenOffice project has a number of them (http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Dictionaries) and they can be converted to the Jazzy word list format with JazzyDicts (https://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzydicts/).

Comment: You can also download a longer English dictionary list of words for Aspell using this nice script: http://app.aspell.net/create to use it in Jazzy.

Comment: There are also the WinEdt dictionaries here: http://www.winedt.org/Dict/

Comment: Good tutorial on how to use Jazzy: http://moderntone.blogspot.com/2013/02/tutorial-on-jazzy-spell-checker.html

Answer (score 38):

Another good library is JLanguageTool http://www.languagetool.org/usage/
It has a pretty simple api and does both spelling and grammar checking/suggestions.

```java
JLanguageTool langTool = new JLanguageTool(Language.AMERICAN_ENGLISH);
langTool.activateDefaultPatternRules();

List<RuleMatch> matches = langTool.check("Hitchhiker's Guide tot he Galaxy");
for (RuleMatch match : matches) {
    System.out.println("Potential error at line " +
        match.getEndLine() + ", column " +
        match.getColumn() + ": " + match.getMessage());
    System.out.println("Suggested correction: " +
        match.getSuggestedReplacements());
}
```

You can also use it to host your own spelling and grammar web service.

Comment: This library's Java API direct link: http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-api

Comment: This has a *ton* of dependencies and is powered by hunspell, which is mentioned in another answer.

Answer (score 3):

Check out JSpell by Page Scholar, http://www.jspell.com.

Answer (score 3):

Another possible alternative is JOrtho http://jortho.sourceforge.net

I haven't used it yet, but I'm evaluating the current Java Open Source spellcheckers to figure out which one to use.

Answer (score 2):

[Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) looks like it could be of use.  It is written in C++ but a java interface according to the home page.  Tri-licensed under GPL, LGPL and MPL so you shouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: Good suggestion. Using a C++ library from Java will just add too much complexity for me, as I'd need to compile it for a number of different platform. But that definitely looks like a well-rounded library.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [JaSpell](http://jaspell.sourceforge.net/). It comes with an internal spell checking engine or you can use [aspell](http://aspell.net/). Since the source is available, you can also attach aspell-like engines easily (like [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/)).

It comes with filters for TeX and XML and it has support for suggestion engines like keyboard distance, common misspellings (where you can define words and their replacements for common typos), Levenshtein distance, and phonetic distance.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/

This is a simple Java API that makes it very easy to call Google's spell checker service from Java applications.

I tried it and it works very well.

Comment: This service is not working any more. Seems like Google shut it down.

Comment: I am voting down since this service doesn't work anymore

Comment: -1 because not working anymore

Comment: It looks, Google spell checker doesn't work anymore. When you open the link, It is written on web page that "This project will soon be migrated to Github" - not sure when.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Suggester](http://www.softcorporation.com/products/spellcheck/index.html). It is  open source, free, and supports all of the above listed languages.