# Do you know a free or open source website spell-checker?

Tags: java, tomcat, web-applications, spell-checking, languagetool

We are looking for a free to use website software for spell checking our sites before they go to production.  A basic search online took me to these pages: 
     [Net MECHANIC](http://www.netmechanic.com/cobrands/FutureQuest/spell_check.htm) 
     [Text Trust](http://www.texttrust.com/) 
     [Orango](http://orangoo.com/spell/)

I did the trial in NetMechanic and I got a bogus email with no result and encouraging me to buy their paid subscription.  Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A project I work on is about to implement [Jazzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy) as a spell-checker. It's free, open-source (LGPL) and the dictionaries are simple text files and easy to add your own words too.

**Edit to add:**
We're spell-checking HTML with it too, and I think it does this "out-of-the-box".

Comment: Related question here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library

Answer (score 0):

[NetSpell SpellChecker](http://sourceforge.net/projects/netspell/). It's Free and Open-Source.

Edit: It's not for Java, but it is for .NET; and I don't think it'd be too difficult to port it over to Java.

Answer (score -2):

Give [websitespellchecker.com](https://www.websitespellchecker.com) a try, it's not free but it's painless. It scans the entire site and provides a PDF report showing where the errors are. The PDF report is checked over before you receive it ensuring you only get issues you'd be interested in. Also, as it's a PDF it's easy to pass onto whoever needs to fix the issues.