# Open source spell checking library for Java

Tags: java, linux, nlp, spell-checking, languagetool

I am looking for free and open source spell checking libraries (could check whether spelling is correct for a given string, and any suggested corrections for a mis-spelled string), which could be easily integrated into Java program on Linux. English language spell checking is a must requirement,spell checking for other languages is a better to have requirement.

Any suggestions?

BTW: libraries for C/C++ is also ok.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library - It has been answered

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Looking for Java spell checker library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net/) is a LGPL spelling library that you can use but it's implemented in C++.  Although I haven't used it there's a Java library called [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) that aims to be a Java re-implementation of Aspell.  It's a fairly old project but it looks like it still works.

Edit:

Just discovered that [Hunspell](http://hunspell.sourceforge.net/) is a better project for spell checking.  It powers Open Office.org, Firefox and Google Chrome.  There's also a project with that supplies [JNA wrappers](http://dren.dk/hunspell.html) so you can use it in Java.