# Java method for checking spelling

Tags: spell-checking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for Java spell checker library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library)

Is there any method for checking spelling of english words.

I have word game where I have to select letters to form a word and then check it for spelling, if correct then show on the panel.

the methods and the use of these methods, please.

thanks.

Comment: Have you done any research in to this yourself?

Comment: You need to be more specific.  A fully functioning spell checker will find potential matches from a dictionary and the algorithms for this are complicated.  Are you saying that the word to spell is already known and you are checking spelling of the user supplied word?

Comment: an user supplied word which is to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

You need a dictionary of accepted words, and compare against that.  If you want to recognize similar words then you'll want to start with prefixes and suffixes and move on to levenstein(?) distances

... Or you can use String.equals()