# Use bilingual spelling dictionary in java code

Tags: java, dictionary, spelling

I've seen some similar topics, but they don't seem to solve my problem.

I'm developing a java application where spell checking is required. The two languages I have to use are English and Greek.
So I need to check a word's spelling and if it's incorrect, to replace the wrong word with the appropriate one.

Does anyone have experience on how to do this?

Comment: What's wrong with the accepted answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library ? The first comment mentions how to get non-english dictionaries.

Comment: Oups...I didn't pay attention to that comment. Thanks, I'll check it out.