# Checking whether a string is a valid English word in Java

Tags: java

I want to know if there is an open source/free library available to check whether a string is a valid English word or not in Java.

Comment: I sure you can find the answer from google.
keyword: java dictionary check

Comment: You mean like a dictionary look-up table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Looking for Java spell checker library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if it is a little bit outdated, and not updated since 2005, [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/) seems to be a valid solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this work for your problem... http://www.languagetool.org/usage/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Jazzy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/files/Dictionaries/English/) (Jazzy - Java Spell Check API) im not sure if it provides any direct option to check whether a word is valid or not but guess with some tricks you can achieve this