# Getting google spelling fixer data to program

Tags: c++, google-search

I'm intrested in getting the data of the google spelling fixer into my program.
For example when I print "my name si" the program search in google and return this:
[image]

"my name is"

I'm programming in c++ but I can learn another languge if it suits this kind of tasks more.
The general goal is to get info from the web into my programs.
How can I acomplish this mission?
Thenx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this article titled [How to write a spelling corrector](http://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) by Peter Norvig

Go through the "how it works section" for background knowledge

Comment: I was looking more for the ability to get info from a web page and less to create a corrector myself, that wasn't the main goal of the program. Do you have any suggustions to deal with this goal?

Comment: I have not used this one http://code.google.com/p/google-api-spelling-java/ but it should be good given that it internally uses the google service

Comment: There is a similar thread but for java here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library

Comment: @Raza is there a c++ version of google api spelling?