# Java program:How to get current input method's state?(Chinese or English)

Tags: java, awtrobot

Because I just used a robot class to mimic a user to input some words to a notepad, and now I want to input some Chinese sentences by using system's input method (that looks very vivid).

How to detect if the input method is in Chinese or not?

Answer (score 0):

I guess what are you looking for is some kind of a language tools or spell checker. Try to visit [this](http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-spell-checker) tools website, also some topic of spell checker tool is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559510/looking-for-java-spell-checker-library) . Good luck.